# Пропадают слайды slick-carousel на mozilla

Tags: javascript, html, css, slick.js

Есть вот такой сайт http://site.pincet.by/depilation/ , там есть слайдер(внизу, где слайды внутри телефона), так вот 1-ые два слайда показывает, а следующие просто исчезают. Если прокликать по стрелке быстро, то можно увидеть больше 2 слайдов, но потом они всё равно исчезают. Не могу понять причину, может кто сталкивался или может разобраться?
Вот такой код для самого слайдера(на самом деле их 2, но интересует только 1-ый, который в картинк етелефона)

```js
$(".reviews__screenshots-phoneSlide").slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: false,
  fade: true,
  centerMode: true,
  centerPadding: '80px',
  asNavFor: ".reviews__screenshots-slider",
  //variableWidth: true,
  cssEase: 'linear',
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 3000,
  //lazyLoad: "progressive",
});
$(".reviews__screenshots-slider").slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  dots: false,
  infinite: true,
  nextArrow: $(".reviews__screenshots-arrowRight"),
  prevArrow: $(".reviews__screenshots-arrowLeft"),
  //autoplay: true,
  //autoplaySpeed: 3000,
  pauseOnHover: true,
  variableWidth: true,
  asNavFor: ".reviews__screenshots-phoneSlide",
  //lazyLoad: "progressive",
  responsive: [{
      breakpoint: 901,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
      },
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 768,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
      },
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 568,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
      },
    },
  ],
});
```

Comment: в мозиле 6 слайдов, в хроме 4 )  еще висят какие-то обработчики на нем ? или как формируются эти слайды ?

Comment: Нет, обработчиков нет. Просто картинки там, 6 штук и должно быть.

Comment: так понял, что синхронизируешь два слайда - скинь код второго

Comment: Блин, сразу же хотел оба, а в итоге залил только 1 и не тот, поправил вопрос. Первый - это мой с телефоном, 2-ой - это с которым он связывается.

Comment: попробуй из телефона перекинуть centerMode и автоплей.... т.е. на телефоне это удалить, а на 2ом поставить. Скрипт все= на 2ом работает )

Comment: Не помогло, слайды всё равно пропадают. Мне кажется дело там в css скорее. Однако самое странное, что 1-ые два слайда показывает, а остальные нет, хотя css одинаковый для всего.

Comment: Похоже дело было в том, что слайдер в телефоне position:absolute; , но почему это так работает на мозиле, я не понимаю, учитывая то, что хроме всё нормально.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело было в том, что мой слайдер в телефоне был position:absolute;, это и ломало его.
Однако разобраться почему это его ломает в мозиле ещё предстоит.